# Counter incrementing by 2 rather than 1

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

Currently trying to useState with prevState for incrementing and decrementing my counter but it is
\ incrementing and decremeting by 2 each time, even though I only want it to do it once each time.

I've tried to return updatedProducts[index].count however it returns an error that products.map is not a function, I assume because I am no longer passing in an array.

```
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([])

  const decrementCount = (index) => {
    setProduct((prevState) => {
      const updatedProducts = [...prevState];
      // create min for the count, can not go less than 0
      // math.max() returns the value that is the smallest
      const newCountdown = Math.max(0, updatedProducts[index].count - 1)
      updatedProducts[index].count = newCountdown;
      return updatedProducts
    });
  }

  const incrementCount = (index) => {
    setProduct((prevState) => {
      // const updatedProducts = [...prevState];
      const updatedProducts = [...prevState];
      // create max for the count, can not go more than 10
      const newCount = Math.min(10, updatedProducts[index].count + 1)
      updatedProducts[index].count = newCount;
      // console.log('This is the count'+updatedProducts[index].count)
      return updatedProducts;
    });
  }

  const url = 'http://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json?brand=maybelline'

  async function callAPI() {
    try {
      const request = await fetch(url);
      if (request.status === 200) {
        console.log('Success!');
        const response = await request.json();
        // this spreads the items from the response call and adds a count of 1 to each card/image
        const productsWithCount = response.map((item) => ({
          ...item, count: 1

        }));
        setProduct(productsWithCount);
      } else {
        console.log(`Server error: ${request.status}`);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Fetch error: ${err}`);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search here" />

      <button onClick={callAPI}>Click to get API</button>
      <div className='shopCards grid grid-cols-5'>
        {
          product.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={item.id}>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M21 8.25c0-2.485-2.099-4.5-4.688-4.5-1.935 0-3.597 1.126-4.312 2.733-.715-1.607-2.377-2.733-4.313-2.733C5.1 3.75 3 5.765 3 8.25c0 7.22 9 12 9 12s9-4.78 9-12z" />
                </svg>
                <img src={item.api_featured_image} ></img>
                <div className='addToCart'>
                  <div className='productQuantity'>
                    <button onClick={() => incrementCount(index)} value={item.id}>
                      +
                    </button>
                    <p>{item.count}</p>
                    <button onClick={() => decrementCount(index)}>
                      -
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <button>
                    Add to cart
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          }

          )
        }

      </div>
    </div >
  )
}

export default Shop
```

Comment: I don't really know why but if you remove `StrictMode`, it doesn't trigger twice

Comment: My page returns an 'Element type is invalid' error if it is removed unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const updatedProducts = [...prevState];` is a shallow copy, and doesn't copy the objects within the array. React state should be immutable, but the line `updatedProducts[index].count = newCountdown;` mutates `prevState`.

Try

```js
const updatedProducts = prevState.map(e => ({...e}));
```

which copies each object within the array as well as the array. It's then safe to use `=` to mutate the copy.

If your objects have nested objects or arrays, you'll want to copy those, too, as the above code only performs a shallow copy of each object.

Also, `<StrictMode>` can cause double renders, so check that that's not interfering.

Naming nitpick: I'd use `[products, setProducts]` because it's an array of multiple products.

Runnable, simplified example you can work from:

```js
const url = "http://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json?brand=maybelline";

const Products = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);

  const fetchProducts = () => {
   fetch(url)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data =>
       setProducts(data.map(e => ({...e, count: 1})))
     );
  };

  const increment = index => {
    setProducts(prevState => {
      const newState = prevState.map(e => ({...e}));
      newState[index].count++;
      return newState;
    });
  };

  const decrement = index => {
    setProducts(prevState => {
      const newState = prevState.map(e => ({...e}));
      newState[index].count--;
      return newState;
    });
  };

  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <button onClick={fetchProducts}>Show products</button>
      <ul>
        {products.map((e, i) => (
          <li key={e.id}>
            <span>{e.name}</span>
            <button onClick={() => increment(i)}>+</button>
            <span>{e.count}</span>
            <button onClick={() => decrement(i)}>-</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Products />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I'd prefer to search by `id` rather than index though--most of the time, you'll need to send a request to a an API to persist the changes in a database, which will be based on id, not index.

Note also that the above snippet doesn't necessarily reproduce your problem if you switch `prevState.map` to `[...prevState]`, since mutation is one of those things that can misleadingly appear to work. While there may be another factor (I don't see any other obvious problems), this is still an important issue to fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Would you say it is best practice to not use spread operator on prevState and rather use map?

Comment: Not much choice here, because spread alone doesn't copy deep enough.